# How to add image in OSM with the authorisation key using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to get a layer from the WMS request but the problem is the URL expects the authorization header. I have tried implementing that I am getting the error.

> Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Here is my JS code:

```
$(function() {
                var params = {
                    "FORMAT": "image/png",
                    "TRANSPARENT": "true",
                    "VERSION": "1.3.0",
                    "LAYERS": "1",
                    "WIDTH": "1000",
                    "HEIGHT": "1000",
                    "CRS": "epsg:3857",
                    "BBOX": "bbox",
                };
      
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://wms-url/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&" + $.param(params),
                    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("KEY","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                    },
                    type: "GET",
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var image = new ol.layer.Image({
                        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                            imageLoadFunction : function(image){
                                image.getImage().src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(data); //Getting error here
                            },
                            imageExtent: extent,
                        }),
                    })


                    map.addLayer(image);
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    alert("error");
                });
             });
```

When I am logging the response I am getting the image/png data in the response I think I am doing something wrong in adding the layer in OSM using OpenLayers.

Comment: This is not really a GIS question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277677/how-to-choose-between-window-url-createobjecturl-and-window-webkiturl-creat

Comment: I have tried that but i am getting this response `blob:null/6663c92c-1d6c-403e-b573-e8cb239b39c4` and the layer is not getting added

Comment: I mean to say its not getting loaded from the blob response

Comment: What response are you getting from the request?  The text "bbox" is not a  valid WMS bbox.  For ImageSatic you wouldn't need an imageLoadFunction as you could set the source url  to the object url.  But if you want to use a dynamic WMS layer which needs authentication you should use the imageLoadFunction to set the header as the bbox will change as you pan and zoom the map..